# Sub-sampling to quantify mean and errors

Tags: mean, error, subsampling

I have a model in matlab that, ultimately, outputs a yes or a no depending on certain input parameters. There's a degree of randomness in the model, so by runnning it 1000 times, I may end up with 200 yes's and 800 no's, but if I run it 1000 times again, I might end up with 180 yes's and 820 no's. I could repeat this approach a few times and get a pretty stable mean number of yes's, but this would be rather slow.

So, I wondered if there is a way to estimate a stable mean and error without resorting to repeatedly running the model?

As an alternative, I wondered if I could run the model 1000 times, and then randomly sample the results to give me a few hundred new data sub-sets each with, say, 100 results. I could then work out the proportion of yes's in each of these sub-sets, and take a mean and standard deviation. Would this work? Does it have a name?

I wondered as well about bootstrapping, but wasn't sure it was appropriate in this case.